# Calling lambda expression directly? (Ex. Action.Invoke(()=>{})

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, action

Sorry for the bad title. I want to do the following in .NET 3.5:

```
void Invoke(Action callback)
{
   callback();
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's some already built-in classes which already have this functionality. For example, if I could do the following I would be happy (but I know I can't):

```
Action.Run(()=>{}}
```

I know there's a bunch of solutions to this problem, like writing my own helper class, or an extension. But as I said, I'm wondering if this is possible to do without any of that.

To clarify:

I want this solution because I have a method definition like this:

```
private void HelloWorld(Action callback)
{
#if DOTNET4.0+ //This code won't be compiled for DOTNET3.5
   Action.Run(async ()=>{
      await someTask;
      callback();
   });
#else //This code will be
   callback();
#endif
}
```

The reason I don't wanted to use Task.Run(...) Is because I wanted to minimize the amount of code dependent on .NET4.0+. If there's is no alternative to Task.Run(...), then I will go with it.

Comment: Why would you want to add such a layer of indirection? What advantage might `Action.Run(()=>{Foo();})` have over just `Foo()`?

Comment: Because I need to do the following `Invoke(async ()=>{await ...})` so that my method definition doesn't need the async keyword (please don't ask me why (I have my reasons)! ;) ).

Comment: So     `Task.Run(async () => {await FooAsync();})`

Comment: Can't use Task since I'm on .NET3.5! I know it's a bit contradicting that's why I didn't mention the async-keyword in the post.

Comment: there is no support async/await in .net 3.5 as that requires `Task`.

Comment: I don't get it, so despite your request not to ask, here I am asking... What are you really trying to?

Comment: Uhh, guys thank you but... I know that there is no support for async, task etc. That's why I didn't mention it in the post. I only wanted to know if there  existed a method as the one I requested. Ignore the fact about async etc, it's really not relevant. :)

Comment: Edited my post to explain why I wanted what I wanted.

Comment: So Task came out of Reactive Extensions and was available for .Net3.5. You might choose include https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/ so that you can get more consistency in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this! Although the chance that I will rewrite this code is very high, therefore I wanted a very "basic" solution (and not rely on some helper class that i created for this most-likely temporary code).

Comment: You can use `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` to simulate a simple task. Plenty examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/22t547yb(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a void lambda with no arguments can be called like this:

```
((Action)(()=>{}))()
```

or

```
((Action)(()=>{})).Invoke()
```

You always have to assign a type to the lambda (even implicitly), before you are allowed to work with it.

Comment: Thank you! This is the basic solution i was looking for!